# Cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [14]' to 'LPCWSTR'

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, lpcwstr

I am getting this error:

```
cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [14]' to 'LPCWSTR'
```

With the code below. It is supposed to be C but at best visual studio 2012 offers an empty c++ project:

```
#include "windows.h"

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hinst, HINSTANCE hprevinst, LPSTR cmdline, int showcmd)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Merhaba Dunya", "Merhaba", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

What is incorrect?

Comment: @FlorisVelleman You beat it to me by 9 seconds!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems your current settings are set up so that WinAPI functions expect wide strings:

```
MessageBox(NULL, L"Merhaba Dunya", L"Merhaba", MB_OK);
```

Comment: thanks but still not working. seems like i need to get native C IDE.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG I don't know what do you mean by that... what's a "native C IDE"? How would this have anything to do with the IDE?

Answer (score 6):

Right click on your project, go to properties under configuration properties -> General and change character set to Use multi-byte character set.

Answer (score 2):

There steps below worked for me:

1. Right click on your Project in Solution Window, then select Properties menu item.
2. Click on General under "Configuration Properties" in Property Pages
3. At "Character Set" setting: change "Use Unicode Character Set" to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set", then click on OK button
4. Rebuild your project to see how it works