# MessageBoxW cannot convert

Tags: wxwidgets, lpcwstr

I am using wxWidgets 2.9.4 in Visual Studio 2012 and I keep getting these two error messages:

Error   1 error C2664: 'MessageBoxW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char *' to 'LPCWSTR'

IntelliSense: argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"

My code is:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    std::string msg;
    StringFromFormatV(&msg, format, args);
    retval = IDYES == MessageBox(0, msg.c_str(), "ERROR! Continue?", MB_ICONQUESTION | MB_YESNO);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char \[14\]' to 'LPCWSTR'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592906/cannot-convert-parameter-2-from-const-char-14-to-lpcwstr)

Comment: In addition to the solution below, why do you use Win32 `::MessageBox()` anyhow if you're using wxWidgets? Just use `wxMessageBox()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are compiling your project using multi-byte characters as default. You can change that in your project's properties, or you can use `msg.wc_str()`, or even enforce the use of `MessageBoxA` instead of using the macro `MessageBox`.

Comment: My Character Set is set to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" though, that is what is stumping me.

Comment: Thats the problem, change it to the simple one, I don't remember the name exactly.

Comment: Character Set: Not Set